# AWS Inspector - Teraform deployment

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, inspector

I am working over AWS trying some security features like securityhub, and I was deployed it trough terraform. Now I am interested in apply from terraform AWS inspector after try it from aws console; but I don't find a way to configure this implementation applying an account delegation and full freatured deployment, I was only found the way to apply the old classic inspector over aws. There is a way to implement aws inspector v2 with terraform?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just saw thath Inspector v2 is a new feature (released one month ago) and at the moment is is not supported by Terraform.

[Terraform GitHub Issue](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-aws/issues/22330)

Comment: Thank you very much Danilo for your answer.